# Add and populate a 'property' to tracked Mixpanel (mixpanel.com) events

Tags: python, analytics, mixpanel

Is there a Mixpanel-API to add and populate a 'property' to all the 'events' of a particular type. This, I want to do every day, via a cronjob, for all the matching events for the previous day.

For clarity, take this example; Suppose I have events being tracked to Mixpanel with these details:

{'name' : 'page_type',
 'action' : 'landing',
 'date' : '14-04-2015',
 ...
}.

Now I want to add a property 'num_displayed_items' with an event-details dependent value, like:

{'name' : 'page_type',
 'action' : 'landing',
 'date' : '14-04-2015',
 ...,
 **'num_displayed_items' : some_var**,
}.

Answer (score 0):

There's no (documented) API method that will allow you to update/modify an event.

You might consider associating the additional 'property' to a People object that's associated with the event.

HTTP API reference: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/http

Answer (score 0):

One clunky way to do it is to export the events, modify them and import them again. You can read in [this post of mine](https://www.startersquad.com/blog/how-to-recover-events-that-youve-sent-to-the-wrong-mixpanel-account/) how you can export, modify and import events.

The recipe that you would have to implement (left as an exercise to the reader) goes like this:

- export all events,
- reset (or create new) project,
- modify event json as desired,
- import events into new/reset account.

There is a bit of experimentation to be done here. You're welcome to edit the answer once you have the code.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way of doing that. But we actually wanted to do it frequently back then, making this method very unsuitable. We have since, obviated the need to do this. Cheers!

Comment: @akshay yeah, the other answer would be: don't even try, which is even more unsatisfying. Glad to hear you're not in this fix anymore.